# "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server." under specific cirsumstances

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've been developing a new application using the latest version of ASP.NET MVC 5 and Entity Framework 6.

I have a controller that returns an empty view that's my AirlineController. It functions when I'm not logged in, but when I log in, I get an unhappy error screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hr5bv.png

The relevant code is here: http://hastebin.com/unugupoguq.cs

I have a chat log from ##asp.net on freenode with someone trying to help that might be useful too: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2KmV.png

I'm using SQL LocalDb locally and Azure with SQL Server for deployment and I'm getting the issue on both deployments.

**EDIT:**

The connectionStrings section of my web.config is this locally:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Fids2014.mdf;Initial Catalog=Fids2014;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Post the `<connectionStrings>` section of your web.config. There's a lot of useful information in the yellow screen of death you linked to.

Comment: how is your IdentityDbContext build ?

Comment: I believe that IdentityDbContext is an MVC builtin:
`Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext<TUser>`

Comment: I've had this error on and off for the last few months. Comes and goes by itself without any involvement from me. Microsoft declines to investigate - "buy a support contract" they say. Not going Azure for production while something as simple as this is flaky.

Comment: It feels like something I've got wrong with ASP.NET MVC, not even just Azure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ended up "solving" the problem by scrapping the project and moving code over. Nothing visible changed, but now the project works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I have managed to fix it by installing SQL Server 2012 Express local DB, (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062), after that I restarted visual studio and it worked.